# put data to the idea

Tags: meaning

I dont really understand the underlined phrase of this sentence:
"Although scientists have long suspected this to be the case, the new study is said to be one of the first to put some hard data to the idea."

The whole article can be found here: http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/3123921.stm

Does it mean: "data supports the idea"?

Answer (score 2):

The phraseology is a little careless in my opinion. I don't believe that it necessarily means that the data supports the idea. In fact sufficient data might eventually refute the idea.

I think it is supposed to mean

"Although scientists have long suspected this to be the case, the new study is said to be one of the first to test the idea with hard data."

Comment: I find it to be artful rather than careless but I do agree with your interpretation.

Comment: I think my objection is that we normally apply a theory to data. We don't apply data to a theory unless the theory is well-established and the data is suspect.

Comment: You seem to be taking "apply" to mean "to question".  The original word was "put".  The english used here is metaphorical and I've simply interpreted it as, "find relevant".  Both the data and the theory would still be open to question.

Comment: I don't think I did take it as meaning question. For me 'put' is nearer to 'apply' than it is to 'find relevant.'  I don't think it's worth arguing over an interpretation though.

Answer (score 0):

hard data = evidence - it is a relevant phrase

Comment: Hello, Deb. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard-data) defines _hard data_ as: information such as ​numbers or facts that can be proved. This speaks of the reliability of the data, not whether it supports or disproves a hypothesis. So one has to assume that the 'to' in  'put some hard data to the idea' is intended to signify 'supportive evidence'. But I agree with chasly that it's clumsy.